# Need to merge single array elements having same key value pair

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array I need to merge corresponding key=> value pair having same date

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-20
            [Whreceived] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-02-24
            [Whreceived] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-21
            [Whreceived] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-20
            [InProcess] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-19
            [InProcess] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-25
            [OnHold] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-19
            [WhInwardDone] => 1
        )

)
```

Expected output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-20
            [Whreceived] => 1
            [InProcess] => 1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-02-24
            [Whreceived] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-21
            [Whreceived] => 1
        )



    [4] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-19
            [InProcess] => 1
            [WhInwardDone] => 1

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-25
            [OnHold] => 2
        )



)
```

Basically I need single array having unique dates with all its corresponding values

Comment: Did you try do it with simple `for-loop` and `array_merge`? (recommend you use the date as keys in the result array and then do `array_values`)

Comment: yes I did try array merge  but it merges only having same key but I need other value also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `array_reduce`, checking for the existence of the date in the new array and if it exists, merging the current value with that value, otherwise creating a new value in the new array.

```
$merged_array = array_reduce($array, function ($c, $v) {
    if (($k = array_search($v['CreatedDate'], array_column($c, 'CreatedDate'))) !== false) {
        $c[$k] = array_merge($c[$k], $v);
    }
    else {
        $c[] = $v;
    }
    return $c;
}, array());
print_r($merged_array);
```

Or you can use a simple foreach loop :-)

```
$merged_array = array();
foreach ($array as $v) {
    if (($k = array_search($v['CreatedDate'], array_column($merged_array, 'CreatedDate'))) !== false) {
        $merged_array[$k] = array_merge($merged_array[$k], $v);
    }
    else {
        $merged_array[] = $v;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-20
            [Whreceived] => 1
            [InProcess] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-02-24
            [Whreceived] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-21
            [Whreceived] => 1
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-19
            [InProcess] => 1
            [WhInwardDone] => 1
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-25
            [OnHold] => 2
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/hYXEF)

Answer (score 0):

try below `Easy Understand trick`:

```
$array_mix = array(
        array("CreatedDate" => "2019-03-20","Whreceived" => 1),
        array("CreatedDate" => "2019-02-24","Whreceived" => 1),
        array("CreatedDate" => "2019-03-21","Whreceived" => 1),
        array("CreatedDate" => "2019-03-20","InProcess" => 1),
        array("CreatedDate" => "2019-03-19","InProcess" => 1),
        array("CreatedDate" => "2019-03-25","OnHold" => 1),
        array("CreatedDate" => "2019-03-19","WhInwardDone" => 1),
    );
```

using `foreach`:

```
    $Newarray = array();
foreach($array_mix as $key => $array_mix_items){

    if($array_mix_items['Whreceived']){
        $Newarray[$array_mix_items['CreatedDate']]['CreatedDate']   = $array_mix_items['CreatedDate'];
        $Newarray[$array_mix_items['CreatedDate']]['Whreceived']   = $array_mix_items['Whreceived'];
    }
    if($array_mix_items['InProcess']){
        $Newarray[$array_mix_items['CreatedDate']]['CreatedDate']   = $array_mix_items['CreatedDate'];
        $Newarray[$array_mix_items['CreatedDate']]['InProcess']    = $array_mix_items['InProcess'];
    }
    if($array_mix_items['WhInwardDone']){
        $Newarray[$array_mix_items['CreatedDate']]['CreatedDate']   = $array_mix_items['CreatedDate'];
        $Newarray[$array_mix_items['CreatedDate']]['WhInwardDone'] = $array_mix_items['WhInwardDone'];
    }
    if($array_mix_items['OnHold']){
        $Newarray[$array_mix_items['CreatedDate']]['CreatedDate']   = $array_mix_items['CreatedDate'];
        $Newarray[$array_mix_items['CreatedDate']]['OnHold']       = $array_mix_items['OnHold'];
    }
}
```

output :

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($Newarray);
echo "</pre>";
```

output in `pre tag`:

```
    Array
(
    [2019-03-20] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-20
            [Whreceived] => 1
            [InProcess] => 1
        )

    [2019-02-24] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-02-24
            [Whreceived] => 1
        )

    [2019-03-21] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-21
            [Whreceived] => 1
        )

    [2019-03-19] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-19
            [InProcess] => 1
            [WhInwardDone] => 1
        )

    [2019-03-25] => Array
        (
            [CreatedDate] => 2019-03-25
            [OnHold] => 1
        )

)
```